# Google re-captcha stop loading suddenly

Tags: recaptcha, grecaptcha

We have implemented the Google re-captcha, it was working fine. File -  https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/releases/CHIHFAf1bjFPOjwwi5Xa4cWR/recaptcha__en.js  giving 404.

On our staging environment -  We have downloaded - https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js and load it locally, once all looks fine. We moved the changes over the Live instance. Till yesterday all looks fine, captcha was loading and working fine but from today not visible on both environment LIVE and Staging, and above mention recaptcha__en.js file giving 404.

1st Ques - Can we download https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js and load it from our base URL?

2nd Ques - what is 'CHIHFAf1bjFPOjwwi5Xa4cWR' in https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/releases/CHIHFAf1bjFPOjwwi5Xa4cWR/recaptcha__en.js?

Answer (score 0):

Found the error, should not download and load https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js from you local setup. It is recommended, even when you load the https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js in browser it is written at the top of file that - `/* PLEASE DO NOT COPY AND PASTE THIS CODE. */` and I missed it .